# Causing a waiting thread to return to userspace

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mutex, futex

Would it be possible to wake up a thread that is waiting on a futex lock? I tried
using a signal mechanism but it does not seem to work. Are there any other approches
I could try out? Below, I've added in an example that might be similar to what I'm
trying to achieve.

1. I have a thread A that acquires a futex lock "lockA" as follows :-
   `ret = syscall(__NR_futex, &lockA, FUTEX_LOCK_PI, 1, 0, NULL, 0);`
2. I have a thread B that tries to acquire the futex lock "lockA", and blocks in the kernel,
   as thread A has acquired the lock.
   `ret = syscall(__NR_futex, &lockA, FUTEX_LOCK_PI, 1, 0, NULL, 0);`
3. If thread B does acquire lockA, another thread, thread C will know about it. If thread B
   does not acquire the lock, thread C would like thread B to stop waiting for the lock, and
   do something else.

So basically, at this point I'm trying to figure out if I can make thread C "signal" thread B
so that it won't block in the kernel anymore. In order to do that, I set a signal handler in
thread B as follows :-

```
struct sigaction act;

act.sa_handler = handler;
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
act.sa_flags = 0;
act.sa_restorer = NULL;
sigaction(SIGSYS, &act, NULL);

...
...

void handler() {
  fprintf(stderr, "Inside the handler, outta the kernel\n");
}
```

From thread C I try to send the signal as :-
  `pthread_kill(tid_of_B, SIGSYS);`

What am I doing wrong? Can thread B be woken up at all? If so, should I use another approach?

[EDIT]
Based on a comment below, I tried checking the return value from pthread_kill and realised that the call was not returning.

Comment: In theory, sending it a signal should work I think. If you make the thread busy wait or `sleep()`, then send the signal, does your handler get called?

Comment: @abligh Thank you for your response. Do you mean thread B should sleep?

Comment: I would recommend not calling async-unsafe functions in a signal-handler, even to debug. If you *really* need to log the invocation of your signal-handler, `write()` to `STDERR_FILENO`.

Comment: in general, calling  `syscall()` is not a good idea as the underlying call numbers and parameter list can change from one OS update to the next.  Suggest to always call the library function.  in this case, I think that calling `mutex_lock()` is simpler, better understood, and much more reliable.

Comment: Which value does the call to `pthread_kill()` return?

Comment: @uki, you seem not to be using futexes in the intended manner (see [`futex(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html)).  In particular, ordinarily you would make a syscall as part of acquiring a futex *only* in the case in which acquisition is contested.  Since that is exactly the case in which you want thread B to avoid blocking, perhaps that's a sign that you want to avoid making that syscall at all.

Comment: Also, if you *do* make the syscall, you should use the `futex()` library function wrapper.

Comment: @alk pthread_kill does not seem to be returning.

Comment: Have you considered using an ordinary pthreads mutex instead of a futex?  As the docs say, "bare futexes are not intended as an easy to use abstraction for end-users".  I strongly recommend that you make your system work, first, as simply as possible.  Only if and where it is not fast enough should you consider engaging futexes or other esoteric techniques to speed it up.  Even then, finding a better algorithm will usually give more advantage than tweaking your existing one to speed it up.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your response, I'll keep that in mind. I'm doing this merely as an intellectual exercise

Comment: @uki I mean try it with thread A sleeping rather than calling `futex()` in order to check whether your signal code is correct. Obviously that's not what you want to do, but it might point you in the right direction (problem specific to `futex()` rather than problem with signal handling).

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

You're using `FUTEX_LOCK_PI` which is *not* in the man page.  I've just looked at the kernel source and a document and it appears this version is only for use inside the *kernel* itself.  It's used to implement a "PI mutex" as a replacement for a kernel `spinlock`.

If you use a `futex`, you must implement the semantics on data in the address it points to.

Here is a crude, pseudocode, and possibly/probably wrong example:

```
int mysem = 1;

void
lock(void)
{

    // atomic_dec returns new value
    while (1) {
        if (atomic_dec(&mysem) == 0)
            break;
        futex(&mysem,FUTEX_WAIT,...)
    }
}

void
unlock(void)
{

    // non_atomic_swap returns old value
    if (non_atomic_swap(&mysem,1) != 0)
        futex(&mysem,FUTEX_WAKE,...)
}
```